# How can I convert sql query to linq query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I want to use linq query in my asp.net project but I could not translate this sql query as linq to c# code I need help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CardValue) FROM `Cards` INNER JOIN `UserAnalyses` ON Cards.Id = UserAnalyses.CardId
```

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it using LINQ code like this:

```
var query = (from c in Cards
            join ua in UserAnalyses on c.Id equals ua.CardId
            select c.CardValue).Distinct();

//Executing the LINQ query
var result = query.ToList();
```

But in order to get a better grasp at what you're doing, please add some info (are you using Entity Framework, what are the models like, ..)

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
context.Cards.Where(q => q.UserAnalyses.Any()).Select(q => q.CardValue).Distinct().ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should **NEVER** "convert" SQL to LINQ. You should create a `Model` that approximately matches your database structure. You can use `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` if you have an existing database. This will get you started.

Second, it is not clear from your question what is the relationship between `Card` and `UserAnalysis` objects (by the way, I used singular intentionally). But let's say, for the sake of argument that One UserAnalysis ==> Many Cards.

Then you will have a `Collection<Card> Cards` member variable in UserAnalysis class.

If you have all that, then you will have a simple LINQ statement:

```
var cards = _context.UserAnalysis.Select(ua => ua.Cards).CardValue.Distinct()
```

But for more specific - please show your Model classes